# Leaflet map with line layer from CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, leaflet

I'm just learning javascript, leaflet, and html. I'm trying to add a line on a Leaflet map based on coordinates from a CSV file. I thought this would be super easy, but after several hours I've had no luck, and haven't found any helpful examples online. This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Loading a line from CSV</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.0/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/csv2geojson@latest/csv2geojson.js'></script>
<script src='D:/java/map_sample/js/papaparse.js'></script>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZWRhaWxleSIsImEiOiJjajJxZG56bXcwMnl6Mndxd2p6bnR6ajJ2In0.es2KsQs3aX_f9hUuQlPmyg';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([34.01, -120.27], 12);

var geoj = csv2geojson.toLine('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evantdailey/map_testing/master/site1.csv', {
    latfield: 'Latitude',
    lonfield: 'Longitude'
});

L.geoJSON(geoj).addTo(map);

</script>
```

When I run that, I get the following error:

```
csv2geojson.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.toLine (csv2geojson.js:192)
at leaflet_geoJSONLayer2.html:24
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or point me in the right direction? The CSV file should be accessible on github

Answer (score 3):

The library doesn't make the AJAX request for you so you are trying to parse the literal string `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evantdailey/map_testing/master/site1.csv`.

You are also trying to call `toLine` with a CSV string as a the parameter when it is requesting a GeoJSON object.

Here is a very basic sample usage:

```
var geoj = csv2geojson.csv2geojson(`lat,lon,name
41.8781,-87.6298,3`, {
    latfield: 'lat',
    lonfield: 'lon'
}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know about AJAX or realize I was only passing it the filename, not the data.